# Google Map is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know the issue is related to the **size** but somehow I am not able to solve it.

[Here](http://goo.gl/o0L1XC) is the link on which I am working on.

If you go to the Location tab on the top and **click** on it, then you can see in **safari**, there is completely grey area and in other browser, if you dont move your mouse after clicking on to the Location tab, then Map would partially grey.

For other browser,

I am using below code to solve the grey area issue:

```
$("#mega-menu-item-581").mouseover(function(){
    $("#menuLocateStore").focus();
    google.maps.event.trigger(menuMap, 'resize');
});
```

But in safari, Dont know How to solve it.Can anyone guide me in this ?

Even I tried it to initialize after the mouseover event without any success.

Other thing that I have tried is to initialize after timeout, but still It did not give any success to me.

The code I am using is added into the snippest.

```js
var searchStoreField = document.getElementById('menuLocateStore');

var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(searchStoreField); //Autocomplete the address
 
var menu_geocoder, menu_map, menu_infoWindow, menu_directionsDisplay, menu_directionsService, menu_geolocationLatlng, menu_markerClusterer,
 menu_markersArray = [],
 menu_directionMarkerPosition = {},
 menu_mapDefaults = {},
 menu_resetMap = false,
 menu_streetViewAvailable = false,
 menu_startMarkerData,
 menu_startAddress,
 menu_autoLoad = true,
 menu_startLatLng; 

function initializeMenuMap() {
 var menu_myOptions, menu_zoomControlPosition, menu_zoomControlStyle, menu_latLng, menu_zoomLevel, menu_mapType, menu_streetViewVisible;
 
 /* If no zoom location is defined, we show the entire world */ 
 menu_startLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng( 57.758665, -101.705156 );
 menu_zoomLevel = 12;


 menu_geocoder       = new google.maps.Geocoder();
 menu_infoWindow    = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
 menu_directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
 menu_directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

 /* Set correct the position of the controls */  
 menu_zoomControlPosition = google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER


 /* Set correct control style */ 
 menu_zoomControlStyle = google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL

 /* Set the selected map type */
 menu_mapType = google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

 menu_myOptions = {
  zoom: menu_zoomLevel,
  center: menu_startLatLng,
  mapTypeId: menu_mapType,
  // mapTypeControl: true,
  // mapTypeControlOptions: {
   // style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
   // position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER
  // },
  //panControl: false,
  //streetViewControl: false,
  //zoomControl: true,
  zoomControlOptions: {
   style: menu_zoomControlStyle,
   position: menu_zoomControlPosition
  },
  //scaleControl: true,
 };

 menu_map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( "menuMap" ), menu_myOptions );
 
}
 
function addMarker( latLng, storeId, infoWindowData, draggable ) {
 var menu_markerPath, menu_mapIcon, menu_marker, 
  keepStartMarker = false;
 
 // if ( storeId === 0 ) {
  // markerPath = wpslSettings.path + "img/markers/" + wpslSettings.startMarker;
 // } else {
  // markerPath = wpslSettings.path + "img/markers/" + wpslSettings.storeMarker;
 // }
 
 // mapIcon = {
  // url: markerPath,
  // scaledSize: new google.maps.Size( 24,35 ), //retina format
  // origin: new google.maps.Point( 0,0 ),  
  // anchor: new google.maps.Point( 12,35 )
 // };
 
    menu_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: latLng,
  map: menu_map,
  optimized: false, //fixes markers flashing while bouncing
  title: infoWindowData.store,
  draggable: draggable,
  storeId: storeId,
 }); 
  
    /* Store the marker for later use */
    menu_markersArray.push( menu_marker ); 
 
    google.maps.event.addListener( menu_marker, "click", function() {
  //setInfoWindowContent( menu_marker, createInfoWindowHtml( infoWindowData, storeId, menu_streetViewAvailable ) );
    });

}

function createInfoWindowHtml( infoWindowData, storeId, streetViewAvailable ) {
    var storeHeader, url, 
  address2 = "",
  newWindow = "",
  streetView = "",
  zoomTo = "",
  windowContent = "<div data-store-id='" + storeId + "'>";
    
  
  
  windowContent += "<a class='infoWindowStore' href='/?page_id=579&store_id="+storeId+"'>"+infoWindowData.store+"</a>"; 
  windowContent += "</div>";

    return windowContent;
}

function setInfoWindowContent( marker, InfoWindowContent ) {
 menu_infoWindow.setContent( InfoWindowContent );
 menu_infoWindow.open( menu_map, marker );
}

function fitBounds() {
    var i, markerLen, 
  maxZoom = 12,
  bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    /* Make sure we don't zoom to far */
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce( menu_map, "bounds_changed", function( event ) {
  if ( this.getZoom() > maxZoom ) {
   this.setZoom( maxZoom );
  }
    });

    for ( i = 0, markerLen = menu_markersArray.length; i < markerLen; i++ ) {
  bounds.extend ( menu_markersArray[i].position );
    }

    menu_map.fitBounds( bounds );
}

function deleteOverlays( keepStartMarker ) {
 var markerLen, i, keepStartMarker=false;
    menu_directionsDisplay.setMap( null );
 
    /* Remove all the markers from the map, and empty the array */
    if ( menu_markersArray ) {
  for ( i = 0, markerLen = menu_markersArray.length; i < markerLen; i++ ) {   
   /* Check if we need to keep the start marker, or remove everything */
   if ( keepStartMarker ) {
    if ( menu_markersArray[i].draggable != true ) {
     menu_markersArray[i].setMap( null );
    } else {
     startMarkerData = menu_markersArray[i];
    }
   } else {
    menu_markersArray[i].setMap( null );
   }
  }

  menu_markersArray.length = 0;
    }
}

/* Trigger the search when the user presses "enter" on the keyboard */
$( "#menuLocateStore" ).keydown( function ( event ) {
    var keypressed = event.keyCode || event.which;
 
    if ( keypressed == 13 ) {
  $( ".locateButton" ).trigger( "click" );
    }
});

$(".locateButton").click(function(){
 
 var keepStartMarker=false;
 deleteOverlays(keepStartMarker);

 var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
 
 var address = $("#menuLocateStore").val();

 geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
   var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
   var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
   var mapData = {
    action: "search_store",
    lat: latitude,
    lng: longitude
   };
 
   var draggable=false;
   $.get( ajaxurl, mapData, function( response ) {
    if ( response.success !== false ) {
     if ( response.length > 0 ) {
    
      $.each( response, function( index ) {
       infoWindowData = {
            store: response[index].store,
            address: response[index].address,
            address2: response[index].address2,
            city: response[index].city,
            country: response[index].country,
            state: response[index].state,
            zip: response[index].zip,
            description: response[index].description,
            phone: response[index].phone,
            fax: response[index].fax,
            url: response[index].url,
            email: response[index].email,
            hours: response[index].hours,
            thumb: response[index].thumb
           };

       latLng = new google.maps.LatLng( response[index].lat, response[index].lng ); 
       addMarker( latLng, response[index].id, infoWindowData, draggable );      
      });
      fitBounds();
     }
     else{
      alert("No stores are near 50 Km from the address you have entered.");
     } 
    }
    else{
     alert("There is some problem. Please try after some time.");
    }
   });    
  }
  else{
   alert("sorry! There is Error !!!");
  }
 }); 
});

google.maps.event.addDomListener( window, "load", initializeMenuMap );
```

**EDITED**

When I check that tilesloaded, at that time it is showing me that tilesloaded.

If tiles are loaded, then why is it showing me the grey area in safari ?

**EDITED**

Okay so when I check in to the Network, I found that all the tiles are downloading and perfect.So what might be the issue for grey area ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$("#mega-menu-item-581").mouseover(function(){
    $("#menuLocateStore").focus();
    initializeMenuMap();
});
```

Comment: I tried it but still the same issue. Its really annoying me :/

Comment: Its working perfectly if Map is not inside the menu.